# 'Us' or 'We' when we remove 'About' from 'About Us'

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

'About Us' is a popular tag in any menu of any website. Of course, it is important to tell the world who you are.

Many companies love to play with words just to add fun and so to engage people more. I do it for my company as well!

But while surfing [a Richmond based (?) company's website,](http://heavenly.co.uk/about-heavenly/) I came across the tab **'US'**. I believe it should be **'We'**. I don't have any problem with **'About Us'** but when you are, for any reason, removing 'About', it should then use 'We' as a pronoun. Because we are not an object *('us')* anymore.

Is it grammatical to use *'us'* instead of *'we'* there?

Comment: yes, it's just okay – consider the famous "Us and Them" by Pink Floyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, the accusative form of a pronoun is the default (*On the Nature of Default Case*, Schütze 2001, starting on page 210).  You need a specific reason to use the nominative form, and the main reason to do so is when it's in subject position:

> **We** like spaghetti.
> ***Us** like spaghetti.　←　ungrammatical

In many contexts, there is no rule calling for the nominative form, so the accusative form is used by default.  For example, when a pronoun appears on its own rather than as part of a sentence:

> Alice: Who's there?
> Bob: **Me.**  　　 　　  　←　OK
>
> Alice: Who's there?
> Bob: ***I.**  　　　　　 　←　ungrammatical

In the example above, the utterance is just a single word, not a complete sentence.  *Me* appears in neither subject nor object function.

If you wanted to use *I* in your reply, it'd have to appear as part of a sentence:

> Alice: Who's there?
> Bob: **I am.**  　　　　　←　OK, *I* appears as part of a sentence in subject function.

Likewise, in your example of *us*, the pronoun appears on its own, and there is no rule calling for the nominative form in this context.  That means you pick the default form, which is accusative:

> **Us.**　　←　OK
>
> **We.**　　←　Strange

When you use *we* by itself, it sounds like you started a sentence and forgot to finish it.  In contrast, using *us* by itself is fine, although of course it's not a complete sentence on its own.

---

Note 1: *Nominative* and *accusative* are traditional labels.  You may be more familiar with the non-traditional labels *subjective* and *objective*.  Remember, though, that pronouns appear in functions other than subject and object.

Note 2: The reason English is described by some linguists as having a "default case" is because it makes things simpler.  You don't have to describe it that way, but you have to list a *lot* of rules to account for every situation accusative forms appear in.  (Unfortunately, none of the reference grammars I have list enough rules to account for every situation!)

Note 3: Regardless of how you describe case, *who* and *whom* have their own rules which are very different from those for *we* and *us*.  Although *whom* is often referred to as an accusative form, it is certainly not the "default" form!  *Who* and *whom* require a separate description.

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case, "US" is better. An interesting example would be a film in 2013, "Her". The director did not adopt the name "She".

I wonder this is not about grammar rules but custom usage?